# reloading userform issue, and code skipping the reload userform statement

Tags: userform, reload

I have a workbook that when it opens automatically opens a user form. When I click on the button I want the code to check if data exists in the spreadsheet. If there is no data a message box will appear asking the user to put data in the spreadsheet. I then want the user form to reload so that the user can click on the button again to attempt to convert the data.
However, I can get the msgbox to appear, but when I click on the msgbox Ok button, i get an Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method on the line where I have tried to show the user form. I had thought that it might be because i am using the code in the button click event.
But when I do the For Loop (to check if data exists) in the Main code, and I click on the button then nothing happens and the workbook closes. I have attempted using Booleans and DoEvents to try and stop the workbook from closing, but it does not seem to help.

In the Thisworkbook i have the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Start_data_conv.Show (vbModeless) 'vbmodeless allows user to interact with the sheets before pressing userform button
End Sub
```

in the button click I have:

```
Private Sub Start_data_conv_button_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
'I have also attempted to put a boolean here with the boolean set to false in initialise or in main code, but has not helped.
'the following For loop will check to see if the source data has been loaded. If there are empty sheets or _
the data hasn't been loaded from the .dat file (each data row in one column)
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) = 0 Or IsEmpty(ws.[B1]) = False Then
        MsgBox "You have not entered the source code or there is an empty sheet. Please enter source", vbCritical
        Unload Me
        Call Reload_userform
        'Start_data_conv.Show (vbModeless) ' if there are empty sheets or not loaded correctly then the userform reloads so that you can try again once data has been loaded correctly
    End If
Next ws

Unload Me
Call org_columns_rows ' this is the main code
end sub
```

the sub reload_useform is just the same line that is in This Workbook - the Start_data_conv.Show (vbModeless) statement. I have tried putting this in the button click event but this is when i get the error message. when I have it in the sub, the workbook just closes without doing anything
I have also attempted to put the For each ws at the beginning of the main code. But the button click just skips over it.

Would appreciate any help you may have to solve the issue

Regards,
Glenn

Comment: Hi,

It has been three weeks now and I have not been able to find a solution to what seems like a simple issue. Could really use some help on this one. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue appeared to be either that I had the same name for the Boolean value as the button name. I have renamed the variable so that it is not the same as the button. The variable was also not declared in the button click or Thisworkbook module (where the userform was called from). I had had the variable publicly in the Main code, and as the main code happens after the userform the boolean variable may not have been set.

Since making those correction - renaming the boolean variable and declaring it in the userform or ThisWorkbook, the code now works.